# Mailboxer N+1 Query detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I managed to install Mailboxer with [this tutorial](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/private-inbox-system-in-rails-with-mailboxer) but i have a recurring error :

```
N+1 Query detected
  Mailboxer::Message => [:sender]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:sender]
N+1 Query method call stack
  app/views/conversations/_messages.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_conversations__messages_html_erb__3829465222244059655_69982701059040'
  app/views/conversations/_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_conversations__messages_html_erb__3829465222244059655_69982701059040'
  app/views/conversations/show.html.erb:27:in `_app_views_conversations_show_html_erb__1439517360344897040_69982700516580'

  app/views/conversations/_messages.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_conversations__messages_html_erb__3829465222244059655_69982701059040'
  app/views/conversations/_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_conversations__messages_html_erb__3829465222244059655_69982701059040'
  app/views/conversations/show.html.erb:27:in `_app_views_conversations_show_html_erb__1439517360344897040_69982700516580'
```

I had another one for :message but i fixed the problem with **includes**. If i try to do the same with :sender, i have this error:

```
Association named 'sender' was not found on Mailboxer::Receipt; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

**Tutorial original code : conversations_controller.rb**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

  def new
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end

  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body,recipients:[])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

**Tutorial original code : show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= link_to "Compose", new_conversation_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <% if conversation.is_trashed?(current_user) %>
        <%= link_to 'Untrash', untrash_conversation_path(conversation), class: 'btn btn-info', method: :post %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Move to trash', trash_conversation_path(conversation), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :post,
                    data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= render 'mailbox/folders' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= render partial: 'messages' %>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <!-- Reply Form -->
        <%= form_for :message, url: reply_conversation_path(conversation) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Reply Message", rows: 4, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <%= f.submit "Reply", class: 'btn btn-danger pull-right' %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Tutorial original code : _messages.html.erb**

```
<% @receipts.each do |receipt| %>
    <% message = receipt.message %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <!-- user avators can go here -->
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= message.sender.username %> <br>
          <small><b>Subject: </b><%= message.subject %></small><br>
          <small><b>Date: </b><%=  message.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M%p") %></small>
        </h4>
        <%= message.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

If i delete <%= message.sender.username %> the problem is solved...

Any ideas ?

Comment: haven't used Mailboxer, so this might not even run, but looking at the code for the gem maybe try `@receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user).includes(message: :sender)` in the `show` method of the controller

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, to fix these [N+1 query problems](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) we use  an `includes` and by passing a hash, we can `includes` nested associations. So looking at this code, calling `receipt.message.sender` is triggering the error, so we have a `Receipt` model, a `message` association on it and a `sender` associated to that. So if we can find where we load the `Receipt` we can add `includes(message: :user)` like we would for any other model.

Digging into the [mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) gem, the `receipts_for` method in your `show` action is just a wrapper for a couple of scopes on `Mailboxer::Receipt`. Since this method just runs some scopes for you, we can chain onto the end of it as if it were a normal `ActiveRecord` `where` chain.

So with all that in mind, we should be able to add on our `includes` and avoid the N+1 query problem, ending up with something like

```
@receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user).includes(message: :sender)
```